# reading prefix in C++

Tags: c++, readfile, fgets, strtok

I am writing a program that reads a text file containing my data together with the unit of measurement e.g.:

```
8.9837 ns    ,  8.9826 ns    ,  8.8998 ns    ,  9.0433 ns    ,  143.5 ps 
13.037 ns    ,  13.027 ns    ,  12.983 ns    ,  13.075 ns    ,  91.1  ps 
-16.18 mV    , -17.842 mV    , -39.78  mV    , -9.44   mV    ,  30.34 mV
```

I am using `fgets` to read each line, then `strtok` to remove spaces and comas. My problem arises when trying to implement a simple function to convert the prefix of my measurement unit. The function receives `char*` and returns `double`. Seems simple enough, but compilation returns:

```
error: ‘prefixing’ was not declared in this scope
```

here is my function:

```
double prefixing( char * prefixit )
{
  if(strspn(prefixit, "m") == 1) return 1e-3;
  ...
  return 1.;
}
```

and here is how I call it:

```
char * p = strtok (line,spliter);
double prefix = prefixing(p);
```

any suggestions on what am I doing wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: Do you mean suffix instead of prefix?

Comment: well, yes and no...
it is prefix to the unit of measurement, but you are right that it is suffix for the value. or I might be getting it completely wrong :D

Comment: Where do you declare the function. How are you including it in your main function?

Comment: It is in separate file from my main(), however it is in the same file with the data reading function where I actually call it. I guess Jack's answer wraps it up completely. Thanks for asking though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably `prefixing` is defined after the line that calls that method. This is not allowed, you need to move the definition or forward declare it to let the compiler know that the function exists, eg:

```
double prefixing(char*); // forward declaration

...
double prefix = prefixing(p);
...

double prefixing(char* prefixit) { // definition

}
```

Comment: yes, that's it. Thanks a lot!
Is there a way to enable some kind of warnings for such errors?

Comment: The compiler error is a warning per se, a serious warning since it halts compilation. Usually warnings are related to code that is syntactically correct but may expose runtime problems, which is not the case here, since the compiler halts before that phase.